# How can i pull just the quantity of the first receipt in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run a SQL where I want to see the first receipt number of a Purchase order number and the quantity received of the first receipt number.

My SQL pulls the first receipt number but I don't get the quantity for the first receipt number instead I get the total receive quantity of the puchase number

here is my SQL:

```
Select
  a.Purchase_Order_Number,
  min(b.Purchase_Receipt_Number) PO_Receipt_NUMBER,  
  min(c.Full_Date) Received_Date,
  sum(b.TRANSACTION_RECEIVED_ITEM_QUANTITY)  PO_Receive_Qty
from f_Purchase_Order    a
join f_Purchase_Receipt b
  on a.Purchase_Order_Key = b.Purchase_Order_Key
join d_Date    c
  on (b.Received_Date_Key = c.Date_Key)
where a.Purchase_Order_Number = '870892'
group by 
  a.Purchase_Order_Number
```

Comment: Could you replace sum with first_value and see if that works too? Leaving everything exactly the way you first wrote it .  Might suit you better than re-write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the first row, don't use `GROUP BY`.  `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
Select po.Purchase_Order_Number,
       pr.Purchase_Receipt_Number,  
       d.Full_Date as Received_Date,
       pr.TRANSACTION_RECEIVED_ITEM_QUANTITY as PO_Receive_Qty
from f_Purchase_Order po join
     f_Purchase_Receipt pr
     on po.Purchase_Order_Key = pr.Purchase_Order_Key join
     d_Date d
     on pr.Received_Date_Key = d.Date_Key
where pr.Purchase_Order_Number = '870892'
order by d.Date_Key
limit 1;
```

Note that I also fixed the table aliases so they identify the tables they come from.

EDIT:

If you want this for all `Purchase_Order_Numbers`, you would use `qualify`:

```
Select po.Purchase_Order_Number,
       pr.Purchase_Receipt_Number,  
       d.Full_Date as Received_Date,
       pr.TRANSACTION_RECEIVED_ITEM_QUANTITY as PO_Receive_Qty
from f_Purchase_Order po join
     f_Purchase_Receipt pr
     on po.Purchase_Order_Key = pr.Purchase_Order_Key join
     d_Date d
     on pr.Received_Date_Key = d.Date_Key
order by d.Date_Key
qualify row_number() over (partition by Purchase_Order_Key order d.Date_Key) = 1;
```

Comment: thank you now how would i get all the first receipt number of every other Purchase order when removing the WHERE clause.

Comment: @kodycarl . . . Ironically, that was my first answer, which I then rewrote.  You would use `qualify`.

Answer (score 0):

You are summing TRANSACTION_RECEIVED_ITEM_QUANTITY across all the items on the Purchase_Order_Number (because of the 'group by'). What you really want is just the information from the first Purchase_Receipt_Number. You can do that with 'top 1' and an 'order by'.

```
Select top 1
  a.Purchase_Order_Number,
  b.Purchase_Receipt_Number,  
  c.Full_Date,
  b.TRANSACTION_RECEIVED_ITEM_QUANTITY
from f_Purchase_Order    a 
join f_Purchase_Receipt b
  on a.Purchase_Order_Key = b.Purchase_Order_Key
join d_Date    c
  on (b.Received_Date_Key = c.Date_Key)
where a.Purchase_Order_Number = '870892'
order by
a.Purchase_Receipt_Number
```

Comment: thank you now how would i get all the first receipt number of every other Purchase order when removing the WHERE clause.